# unable to add dynamic rows in table - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a sort of dynamic table.
Basically, I want user to input some fields and on "Add Row" button, these inputs entered by user will populate the table below and so on, he can enter as many rows he needs. and then extract data from table rows and call service to upload.

What I have done is that I have successfully created the adding row functionality. BUT there is a input in which user selects image and then click ADD ROW button, the issue is image replaced by the previous image on all rows.

```js
var inc = 1;

function add(tableID) {
 console.log(inc);
 var educationInstitute = $("#educationInstitute").val();
 var educationQualification = $('#educationQualification').find(":selected").val();
 var educationAdmDate = $("#educationAdmDate").val();
 var educationGraDate = $("#educationGraDate").val();
 //previewImage("educationImage", inc);
 //var educationImage = $("#educationImage").val();

 var fullPath = document.getElementById('educationImage').value;
 if (fullPath) {
  var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') : fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
  var filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);
  if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
   filename = filename.substring(1);
  }

 }
 filename.replace(/ /g, '');
 filename = filename.slice(0, -4);
 alert(filename);
 previewImage("educationImage", filename);

 var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + educationInstitute + "</td><td>" + educationQualification + "</td><td>" +
  educationAdmDate + "</td><td>" + educationGraDate + "</td><td><img class='previewImage" + filename + "' src='' /></td></tr>";
 $("#educationTable tbody").append(markup);
}

function del(row) {
 $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
   $(this).parents("tr").remove();
  }
 });
}

function previewImage(id, filename) {
 if (document.getElementById(id).files[0]) {
  console.log("ID");
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
   //console.log(e.target.result);
   $('.previewImage' + filename).attr('src', e.target.result);
   inc += 1;
   console.log(inc);
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById(id).files[0]);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset style="min-height:100px;">
  <legend>Education Details </legend>
  <div class="row">
   <button onclick="add('educationTable')">Add Table</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="educationInstitute" id="educationInstitute" placeholder="Institue Name" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="educationQualification" id="educationQualification">
                    <option value="5">--- Qualification ---</option>
                    <option value="5">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="6">Option 2</option>
                </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="educationAdmDate" id="educationAdmDate" placeholder="Admission Date" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="educationGraDate" id="educationGraDate" placeholder="Graduation Date" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" class="form-control imageFileinput" name="educationImage" id="educationImage" data-show-preview="false" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered order-list" id="educationTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Check</th>
          <th>Institute Name</th>
          <th>Qualification</th>
          <th>Admission Date</th>
          <th>Graduation Date</th>
          <th>Degree Scanned Image</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x fa-fw" style="padding-left: 15px;" onclick="AddTableRow.del('educationTable')"></i>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Can anyone tell me, what's I am doing wrong here ?I have spend 2 days already on it.

Comment: code is working now, I added wrong code in first place.

Comment: Can you make this sample in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/bilalzafar256/17o3vcau/

Comment: I don't see any problems in fiddle. Image column contains different classes coresponding to file name. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to make a copy of the input on `add` and append it to the row in a `td` this field can also be hidden and when you want to get the files you can use jquery to get all the those corresponding inputs.

```
  var markup = `
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td>
    <td> ${educationInstitute}</td>
    <td> ${educationQualification}</td>
    <td> ${educationAdmDate}</td>
    <td> ${educationGraDate}</td>
    <td class='file_holder'>
      <img class='previewImage${filename}' src='' /> 
      // append the corresponding input file here for later use
    </td>
   </tr>`;
  $("#educationTable tbody").append(markup);
  $("#educationImage").clone().appendTo("#educationTable tbody tr:last-child .file_holder");
```

Heres the example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17o3vcau/7/)